# Fast mapreduce using multiple ops

Tags: performance, julia

For collections `x` and `y` I want to call a function `f`, and reduce the results using operators from a collection `red`.

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = (2, 4.0, 6, 8.0, 10)
red = (/, *, +, -)

f(x, y::Int) = float(x + y)
f(x, y::AbstractFloat) = x - y
```

That is, I want the result of

```
f(1, 2) / f(2, 4.0) * f(3, 6) + f(4, 8.0) - f(5, 10)   # -32.5
```

The following works but allocates and is ~100x slower than the naive code above.

```
function mapop(f, ops, itrs...)
    i::Int = 0
    op(x, y) = (i += 1; ops[i](x, y))
    mapreduce(f, op, itrs...)
end

mapop(f, red, x, y)
#> -32.5
```

`@code_warntype mapop(f, red, x, y)` shows type instability. `mapreduce` seems to allocate regardless, `@btime mapreduce($*, $+, $1:3, $5:7)`.

**Question**
Is there a fast, preferably non-allocating (alternative / way) to `mapreduce` using multiple functions?

The following loop alternative avoids 30 allocations, and runs faster than `mapop`, however, I fail in getting rid of all allocations.

```
function mapop2(x, y, f, ops)
    val = ntuple(i -> Float64(f(x[i], y[i])), length(x))
    res = first(val)
    for j in eachindex(ops)
        res = ops[j](res, val[j+1])
    end
    res
end
```

Comment: This question is also a good fit for the #performance-helpdesk channel on the [Julia Slack](https://julialang.org/slack/), which is very active.

Answer (score 2):

Another method could be:

```
x = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y = (2, 4.0, 6, 8.0, 10)
ered = (max, /, *, +, -)

f(x, y::Int) = float(x + y)
f(x, y::AbstractFloat) = x - y

foldeval(f, r, x, y) = 
  foldl((r,(x,y,op))->op(r,f(x,y)),zip(x,y,red); init=-Inf)
```

giving:

```
julia> foldeval(f, ered, x, y)
-32.5

julia> @btime foldeval($f, $ered, $x, $y)
  646.577 ns (15 allocations: 432 bytes)
-32.5
```

(note the extra operation making `red` into `ered`)

Answer (score 1):

Passing `i` as an argument to  `op` fixes the warning.

Additionally, some of the slowdown might come from using the splat operator `...`, which makes the form of `mapop` uncertain. On my machine, the following runs a bit more quickly than the original:

```
function mapop(f, ops, itr1, itr2)
           i::Int = 0
           op(x, y) = (i += 1; ops[i](x, y))
           mapreduce(f, op, itr1, itr2)
       end
```

Comment: Some micro-optimizations are certainly possible, such as the splatting - thanks for the heads-up! However, I think the reason why it is slow is the allocations (see `mapop2` in the edited question), and I'm looking to get rid of those.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity,

- `::Function` is abstract, passing a tuple might be slow or hard to reason with about,
- mixing `Int` and `AbstractFloat` is a code smell

I ended up using a tuple `red = (4, 3, 1, 2)` to represent `(/, *, +, -)` and a loop instead.

```
red = (4, 3, 1, 2)
function p(x, y, f, ops)
    res = float(f(x[1], y[1]))
    its = ntuple(i -> float(f(x[i + 1], y[i + 1])), length(ops))
    for i in eachindex(its)
        if ops[i] == 1
            res += its[i]
        elseif ops[i] == 2
            res -= its[i]
        elseif ops[i] == 3
            res *= its[i]
        elseif ops[i] == 4
            res /= its[i]
        end
    end
    res
end

@btime p($x, $y, $f, $red)
#> 7.200 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```